# How to stack seaborn pairgrids in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am making a pairgrid that compares multiple dependent variables to one independent variable. I have the plot and it's exactly the way I want it except for one thing: I don't want the plots to be in one really long line.

Here is my code:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df, y_vars=["W%"], x_vars=["PPG", "FG%", "3FG%", "FT%", 'APG', 'TOPG', 'RPG'], height=4)
g.map(sns.regplot, color=".3")
plt.ylim(0, 1)
```

And this is the output. I would really like to stack them somehow, with the second row also containing the y-axis and ticks. I could obviously just run another pairplot with different variables, but I want them all to be on the same axes. I don't care how they are stacked, 2x2x2x1, 3x3x2, 4x3, anything works. I would just like to figure out how to do it. I was going to make a subplot but sns.PairGrid() doesn't have an ax param. Thanks!

EDIT: I would also like to know to how make the whole pairgrid larger.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `col_wrap`and `height` parameters to `sns.FacetGrid`.

From the seaborn tutorial https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html

```
attend = sns.load_dataset("attention").query("subject <= 12")
g = sns.FacetGrid(attend, col="subject", col_wrap=4, height=2, ylim=(0, 10))
g.map(sns.pointplot, "solutions", "score", order=[1, 2, 3], color=".3", ci=None);
```